# Prepositions with the word "rephrase"

Tags: prepositions, difference

With the word "**rephrase**" which preposition do we use "**as**" or "**to**"?

- You can rephrase this sentence as...
- You can rephrase this sentence to...

Or some other preposition? Or maybe this whole way of saying it is non-idiomatic?

Comment: Both are fine. People in the business (grammarians, linguists) often use ***recast*** instead of ***rephrase***, and in *that* context you could also use ***into*** (but *rephrase X into Y* sounds a bit "affected" to me).

Comment: If you wrote "I would rephrase that to a passive", I would rephrase your rephrasing **to** "rephrase it **as** a passive".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both expression can be correct base on context of use. 
**As** a preposition introducing a basis of comparison, with an object in the objective case.

> You are not as tall **as** me.

While **to**, Used to indicate the indirect object.

> I gave the book **to** him.

Comment: You are not as tall as *I*